# Hyperledger Fabric unit test cross-chaincode invocation without collapsing vendor folder

Tags: go, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have been running into compilation issues when I tried to perform unit testing in golang locally, when trying to instantiate and invoke another chaincode through the MockStub object. Below is my file hierarchy:

```
├── transaction-chaincode
│   ├── transaction.go
│   ├── transaction_test.go
│   └── vendor
└── user-chaincode
    ├── user.go
    ├── user_test.go
    └── vendor
```

The scenario here basically involves one of the chaincode, for example user.go, calling the other chaincode transaction.go. The vendor folders in both directories contain the exact same content.

The problem occurs when I try to instantiate a new instance of the transaction chaincode thru shim.NewMockStub in user_test.go, as the transaction mock object looks for the init method from within transaction-chaincode/vendor/ instead of user-chaincode/vendor/, despite the vendor folders having the same packages (and thus the same method).

I was able to get rid of this error by having a single vendor folder at the parent directory of transaction-chaincode & user-chaincode, but I cannot do so for developmental purposes.  How would you suggest I solve this unit testing problem while keeping the vendor folders in their respective locations?

Comment: What tool are you using for vendoring ? And what import path do you use for packages in the `vendor` directories ?

Comment: @yazgazan Does it matter what tools are being used for vendoring? 
I am using govendor, and the import paths are packages inside the vendor directories are the same as their original packages

Comment: The "conventional" approach is to vendor binaries, not libraries. You can still get away with vendoring inside libraries if your vendoring tool flattens the dep tree (not having nested vendor directories).  You could probably fix your issue by vendoring `user-chaincode` in `transaction-chaincode` and vice-versa, but this will make maintaining vendoring a pain. The best solution, I think, is to do the vendoring in your parent directory (assuming the parent directory is the root of your repository).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are putting shim and other dependencies in each vendor folder. user_test.go then does something like NewMockStub(..., &transaction_chaincode.transaction{}).  You want transaction_chaincode.transaction to bind to user/vendor ?

I don't think that'll happen. The shim import in transaction_chaincode.transaction will bind to its transaction_chaincode/vendor.

If the above understanding is correct, why do you think its a "problem" ?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct.
The problem is that I cannot mock inter-chaincode calls, as certain functions rely on invoking the other chaincode.  For example, I need to use transaction_chaincode.transaction in the user_chaincode_test, but go compiler will complain since user_chaincode_test has no way to look for the binded shim import in transaction_chaincode/vendor; it only references the path to user_chaincode/vendor, which is a mismatch for the initiation of transaction MockStub